# MySql select - groupBy very upset?

Tags: mysql, database, select, optimization, group-by

Maybe this question will be too wide but i really need this so:

I have table with ~80k rows and ~160 columns (a lot i know). And unfortunately i have routine selects for example:

```
SELECT hotelName
     , country
     , locality
     , destination
     , foodType
     , hotelStars
     , departureDateFrom
     , departureDateTo
     , MIN(price) 
  FROM table 
 WHERE locality
   IN (
     '1', '2', '3'
   )
   AND visible IS NOT NULL
   AND departureDateFrom >= (?)
   AND departureDateTo <= (?)
   AND foodType = (?)
   AND hotelStars = (?)
   AND country
   IN (
     '1', '2', '3'
   )
 GROUP 
    BY hotelId 
 ORDER 
    BY price ASC
```

In table are tours. So you can have 250 records with same hotel name, locality... but with different price or departureDate. Primary key is `id` which in this example does not figure. `hotelId` is id from another system and it purpose in this project is only for 'get hotel detail' and groupBy (guarantees unique hotel to results)

point is - i must in every select make `groupBy` + `MIN()` + `order`.

**So main problem is long query time ~250ms per request.**

Average my select have 10-15 columns. I think the problem is because select 'touches' ~70% rows and AFTER that is groupBy and it will return ~200-400 results.

I have most used columns indexed of course. (column for MIN(), groupBy and order are indexed too)

- Caching is imposible in this case.
- Data structure i can't influence.
- Have I some other options to make it quicker?

Will be helpful reduce number of columns? Let say to 60 columns?

---

**UPDATE**

- table was reduced to 65 columns
- all indexes was dropped now is only one (BTREE) on column `hotelId` for groupBy
- some datatypes was optimized for example int(11) to int(5) on `hotelId`

And we are now on **-25%** response time, so now we are on ~190ms.

**Any ideas to get some acceptable response time? Our goal is ~100ms (still a lot but acceptable).**

From profiler:

starting    0.000101 
checking permissions    0.000007 
Opening tables  0.000013 
init    0.000046 
System lock     0.000011 
optimizing  0.000016 
statistics  0.000096 
preparing   0.000020 
Creating tmp table  0.000029 
Sorting for group   0.000011 
Sorting result  0.000006 
executing   0.000004 
Sending data    0.176949 
Creating sort index     0.000916 
end     0.000009 
query end   0.000011 
removing tmp table  0.000602 
query end   0.000008 
closing tables  0.000012 
freeing items   0.000052 
cleaning up     0.000033

Comment: I'm a little unclear. Can you show the expected results and the actual result your getting?

Comment: Will be certainly helpful to fix your database model 160 columns in a table is not only "a lot" but unacceptable. Put your team together and your managers to think and accept that this MUST be fixed. The problem will only grow. That's my humble opinion. Good luck.

Comment: Goose main problem is request time. Results are ok (sorry about unclear a was updated question). Jorge Campos: thx yes we are solving this right now and it looks like ~80 columns will go to another table.

Comment: Do you have an index for all conditional, group and sort rows? Thats not a complex query and 80k rows are not many. How many indexes do you have and is it a dedicated server?

Comment: A.Blub indexes are for all group and sort rows. For conditional rows are indexes for majority but not for all. But in this time we are making 'progressive diet' for columns so we will see...

Comment: If you have different `departureDate` for the same `hotelId`, it is invalid.  It is _wrong_ to expect anything useful for `departureDate` from that query.

Comment: `int(11)` to `int(5)` are totally identical.

Comment: The best index for that query is `locality`.

Comment: Ok do you have pls some other recommendation about way to change this query? I cannot help myself. Maybe using subquery? `departureDate` is different for the same `hotelId` but there i need lowest value too (it is `datetime`). Or make more than one query? `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 500` takes 3ms...

Answer (score 1):

The numbers you provide sound like the entire table is cached in RAM.  So, it is probably not I/O-bound.

Touching 56K rows takes time, regardless.

The best index *may* be this composite `INDEX(col1, col2, col3)`.  (Please adjust your terminology between "rows" and "columns".)

`GROUP BY col5  ORDER BY col6` will necessarily create two temp tables, and sort each.

It is usually improper to `GROUP BY col5` while `SELECTing` columns (col2, col3, col6) that are (apparently) not dependent on the `GROUP BY` column(s).  You will get random values for those three columns.  OK, maybe `col5` is `UNIQUE`, therefor there is no problem.  (Please provide the real names if you can; it will help us to help you.)

I suspect you have a lot of variety in the columns involved, otherwise, I would suggest a "covering" `INDEX(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)` - the first 3 columns in that order, the rest in any order.

Oh, what is the `PRIMARY KEY`?  It may matter.